# Resque does not find ffmpeg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ffmpeg, resque, god

I am using resque to queue some encoding jobs. I have workers that pick up these jobs and do some transcoding. 
The issue is `system "mencoder .."` works fine but `system "ffmpeg .."` throws not found and the same to with `system "qt-faststart .."` 
I installed mencoder using `sudo apt-get install`.
ffmpeg and qt-faststart were built from source. 
So mencoder was in /usr/bin and the other two in /usr/local/bin. 
So, the next thing I tried was using full path in the system command, that also returned not found. 
Then I copied ffmpeg and qt-faststart into /usr/bin.. Still got "Not Found" 
My worker code runs standalone but when god runs it, ffmpeg and qt-fasstart fail to execute. Yes, I have god configured to watch resque. Now, I don't know what else to try! Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obvious and simplest way it just give system method full path.
like this

```
system("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg")
```

but really this should not exist as a problem in first place, especially you saying that coping do not help.

Try to print ENV['PATH'] from resque perform method

it may help to understand what problem is, and of course make sure ffmpeg located in /usr/local/bin/

```
which ffmpeg
```

Comment: It worked with full path and system,but did not with backticks and %x[]. Thanks!